# Does Android Support a server made on ashx or ASP.NET Web Handler file

Tags: android

I have an android application that have to communicate with the server using post method in HTTP. My application work fine whenever i open some other sites having basic page may be html or others but whenever i want to open my server file it gives nothing even though with get method in HTTP.

The blank response from the server can be understandable that what i am getting because i have to send some headers with post method as a request and ashx will send some response to it.

But still as expected by get method in HTTP the basic information of the page have to be retrieved.

for eg. my server url is http://172.17.3.90/RMALite/RLHandler.ashx

and the basic response from the get method have to be like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

Unfortunately i am getting nothing

but whenever i changed the url to open other sites it work fine and i got the response in text html format.

So my Question is, Android require some stuff to handle ASP.NET handler or ashx file as compare to other sites or URL's?

Answer (score 0):

I know it late now but other can get benefit. Below is code snippet which help me to get accomplished same issue.

```
public static String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {

   //targetURL =http://172.17.3.90/RMALite/RLHandler.ashx

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        // Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

         connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""
         + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        connection.setRequestProperty("method-name", "parameter-value");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        // // Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection
                .getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        String field1 = connection.getHeaderField("field1");
        String field2 = connection.getHeaderField("field2");

        return anyArray;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {

        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it would be helpful n much appreciated to [this post](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139)

thanks much

-y